# How to reuse PhoneNumberChooserTask for 2 elements?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, .net-4.5

Currently I have a screen below

[image]

When I press the "C" button I will allow users to select phone number from their contacts.  Once selected it will be displayed in the `textbox`.  I have achieved it.

*For this I have created 2 `PhoneNumberChooserTask` object for each button and used it.*

Now *I wish to have a common object `PhoneNumberChooserTask` for both the buttons and add the respective phone numbers to their textboxes.*

Here is the code, where I'm stuck:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        PhoneNumberChooserTask phNumChoseTask;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            phNumChoseTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
            phNumChoseTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed);
        }

        void phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
                PersonNo1.Text = e.PhoneNumber;  //Add number to Person1 textbox

            //How I can modify to add Person2 number to textbox
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            phNumChoseTask.Show();
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Text Chsng");
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //I'm able to use the same object to show but not add to Person2
            phNumChoseTask.Show();
        }
    }
```

I can feel that there are possibilities but couldn't find a solution.  Please share your thoughts.

Comment: You're creating a problem where there is none. This is some ugly micro-optimization. Although you could simply create a PhoneNumberChooserTask when needed and then discard it, what was the problem with having two? Because you will greatly complicate a sensible piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would clean this up a ton with databinding and using properties.

If you just want a quick and dirty answer though this is it.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        PhoneNumberChooserTask phNumChoseTask;
        bool but1Clicked = false;
        bool but2Clicked = false;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            phNumChoseTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
            phNumChoseTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed);
        }

        void phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK){
               if(but1Clicked)
                   PersonNo1.Text = e.PhoneNumber;  //Add number to Person1 textbox
               else
                   PersonNo2.Text = e.PhoneNumber;  //Add number to Person2 textbox
            }
            //How I can modify to add Person2 number to textbox
            but1Clicked = false;
            but2Clicked = false;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            but1Clicked = true;
            phNumChoseTask.Show();
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Text Chsng");
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            but2Clicked = true;
            //I'm able to use the same object to show but not add to Person2
            phNumChoseTask.Show();
        }
    }
```

## UPDATE

This code is a little more clean

Front end

```
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding tb1,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding tb2,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Tag="1"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Tag="2"/>
    </Grid>
```

Backend

```
 public partial class MainPage  : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        PhoneNumberChooserTask phNumChoseTask;
        private String _tb1;

        public String tb1
        {
            get { return _tb1; }
            set { _tb1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("tb1"); }
        }

        private String _tb2;

        public String tb2
        {
            get { return _tb2; }
            set { _tb2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("tb2"); }
        }

        private Button _ClickedBut;

        public Button ClickedBut
        {
            get { return _ClickedBut; }
            set { _ClickedBut = value; }
        }


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
            phNumChoseTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
            phNumChoseTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed);
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ClickedBut = (sender as Button);
            phNumchoseTask.Show();
        }
        void phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                if (ClickedBut.Tag == "1")
                    tb1 = e.PhoneNumber;
                else if (ClickedBut.Tag == "2")
                    tb2 = e.PhoneNumber;
            }
        }
        void OnPropertyChanged(String prop)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    }
```

Comment: a trick! I thought there must be another clean way.  Since you mentioned about dataBinding I'm interested in that.  Is there a way to do with dataBinding?  Also I'm already doing it for MVVMCross binding for both textboxes.

Comment: When I get back to my desk I'll offer a clean alternative. Give me a few min

Comment: this is an extremally weird usage of binding. There are designed for joining your View and ViewModel which is oblivious of View, I don't get the point of creating a binding where you can simply set the value from code-behind.

Comment: the first solution was much clearer, replacing two button-click-handlers with one that then relies on tag set in xaml is an unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 0):

<s>How about attaching different event handler method for each button and refactor handling logic to single method (`UpdateText` in this example) to reuse more codes :</s>

How about attaching `Completed` event to an `EventHandler` variable. Then set the EventHandler to execute different code for each button click :

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    phNumChoseTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
}

private EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult> _chooserTaskHandler;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //detach current handler
    phNumChoseTask.Completed -= _chooserTaskHandler;
    //set handler action
    _chooserTaskHandler += (o, result) => UpdateText(PersonNo1, result);
    //re-attach handler
    phNumChoseTask.Completed += _chooserTaskHandler;
    phNumChoseTask.Show();
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    phNumChoseTask.Completed -= _chooserTaskHandler;
    _chooserTaskHandler += (o, result) => UpdateText(PersonNo2, result);
    phNumChoseTask.Completed += _chooserTaskHandler;
    phNumChoseTask.Show();
}

private void UpdateText(TextBox textBox, PhoneNumberResult result)
{
    if (result.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        textBox.Text = result.PhoneNumber;
}
```

Note that detach and re-attach event handler is necessary here. Otherwise only action that set before attaching will be executed.

Comment: note, that you attach more and more event handlers to Completed. After three clicks on Button and then three clicks on Button1, unfortunatelly there will be three calls to UpdateText for PersonNo1 and three for PersonNo2..

Comment: @lisp you're right. Updated my answer with another idea : using `EventHandler` variable.